# The speed of my mp3 file changes when using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I use pygame to play my mp3 audio, but its speed changes, I am confused with it.
Below is my code:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('answer.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: I got it from online TTS and save it with binary file. I can play it normally with my music player.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the [Pygame Documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html):

> Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead.

I've never had any trouble using OGG files.  It's easy to convert mp3 to ogg using [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) or another tool (I don't know what OS you're using).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use Linux to develop my code, maybe it is the system which causes it. I will try to find another library to replace it.